# Password protect multiple individual ZIP files on Mac

Tags: mac, encryption, zip, password-protection

Currently, I have an Automator script (Shell Script) which allows me to select multiple files and then create an individual zip file for each.

```
for f in "$@"
do
    zip -j "$f.zip" "$f"
done
```

[image: Screenshot of script]

What I'd like to do is the same thing, but to set a password for each individual file as well. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How would you tell zip the password? Should it be the same for every file, or should it be a keyfile/passphrase-file?

Comment: Hi @Xen2050, the password should be the same for every file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using a shell script already, I was assuming you have access to bash's `read` command to read input to a variable, and a similar `zip` command to Debian's, so you could first store the password to the variable `$pass` with:

```
read -rsp "enter password" pass
```

Where the options mean (from `man bash` or `help read`):

```
-p prompt output the string PROMPT without a trailing newline before
          attempting to read
-r        do not allow backslashes to escape any characters
-s        do not echo input coming from a terminal
```

If you're using a more basic shell like `/bin/sh` / dash, it's read command does not have the `-s` option.

Then zip the files with:

```
zip -j -e -P "$pass" "$f.zip" "$f"
```

Note from zip's man page:

> `-P password`
>   `--password password`
>
> Use  password to encrypt zipfile entries (if any).  THIS IS INSECURE!  Many multi-user operating systems provide ways for any user to see the current  command  line
>                 of any other user; even on stand-alone systems there is always the threat of over-the-shoulder peeking.  Storing the plaintext password as part of a command line in
>                 an automated script is even worse.  Whenever possible, use the non-echoing, inter‐
>                 active prompt to enter passwords.  (And where security  is  truly  important,  use
>                 strong encryption such as Pretty Good Privacy instead of the relatively weak standard encryption provided by zipfile utilities.)

If you're on your own private secure computer with no one watching you, then I wouldn't worry about the potential insecurity of using a password like this.

Or you could omit the password storing & zip's `-P` option, and let zip prompt you for the password (twice) for each file.

---

All together, asking for a password once would look like this:

read -rsp "enter password" pass

```
# If you don't mind seeing the password, it would be safe to verify it:
echo -e "\nUsing this password: $pass"
read -r -n1 -p "Press any key to continue..."
echo

for f in "$@"
do
    zip -j -e -P "$pass" "$f.zip" "$f"
done
```

Or read the password twice in a loop, until the two passwords match:

```
until [ "$pass" == "$pass2" ]; do
  read -r  -p "Enter password" pass
  read -r  -p "Enter password again" pass2
done

for f in "$@"
do
    zip -j -e -P "$pass" "$f.zip" "$f"
done
```

---

It appears there was a problem with the assumption that bash's `read` would work, your automator script isn't running in a regular terminal so you can't get to it's standard input. Here's some other ideas that might work.

### Use bash to ask for more input

From https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7216062?answerId=28893979022#28893979022

> Hiroto User level: Level 5 (7,463 points)
>
> Sep 15, 2015 2:57 AM in response to Scotsman
>
> Hello
>
> Also you might do everything from shell. Something like this.
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> ask () {
>     osascript <<EOF - 2>/dev/null
> tell application "SystemUIServer"
>     activate
>     text returned of (display dialog "$1" default answer "")
> end tell
> EOF
> }
>
> FROM=$( ask 'Enter value for --from' ) || exit
> CREDITS=$( ask 'Enter value for --credits' ) || exit
> CAPACITY=$( ask 'Enter value for --capacity' ) || exit
> LY_PER=$( ask 'Enter value for --ly-per' ) || exit
>
> trade.py run --from "$FROM" --credits "$CREDITS" --capacity "$CAPACITY" --ly-per "$LY_PER"
> ```
>
> Regards,
>
> H

- Once you've got the ask function working, you could only ask for the password (the above example looks like it asks for parameters to run python or something, all you'd need is the ask).

### Run the whole script in a terminal

If you could have it run in a terminal then `read` should work.

### Get automator to ask you for more input

Apparently [this question on apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/222718/passing-arguments-to-run-shell-script-in-automator) looks there's a way to have automator "Ask for text" to try getting another variable.

Comment: Thanks Xen. How would I enter all of this into a single Automator script (or two separate scripts, one for the zipping, and one for password protecting)? Much appreciated.

Comment: If you're using zip, I think it has to compress and password in the same (single) command. But you'd just put the `read ...` command before the for loop, putting it inside the for loop would read a password for each file (if you wanted different passwords). I'll edit it all together at the end of my answer. PS If the answer's useful or the "best" then please do [accept it &/or vote it up](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers), thanks :)

Comment: Thanks Xen, I couldn't get the above scripts to work, what I ended up doing was setting the pass variable in the script. See:

`pass=password

for f in "$@"
do
    zip -j -e -P "$pass" "$f.zip" "$f"
done`

Thanks.

Comment: That works too, and no typing errors either. I think I see the problem, your script isn't running in a regular terminal, so can't `read` from standard input... I'll edit in an idea or two.